# Django ORM queryset

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am learning about the Django ORM and how to make queries, Lets suppose i have two models

```
class Company(models.Model):
    structure = IntegerField()

class Customer(models.Model):
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=now)
    company = ForeignKey(Company)
    friend = BooleanField()
```

- I am writing a function where it can get all companies where their most recently created customer is `friend=True`.

```
def get_companies_with_recent_friend():
  """"
    Returns
    -------
    `list(Company, ...)`
    """
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a subquery to determine this, so:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Company.objects.annotate(
    last_is_friend=SubQuery(
        Customer.objects.filter(
            company=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-created_at').values('friend')[:1]
    )
).filter(last_is_friend=True)
```

The subquery will thus make an ordered collection of `Customer`s that are linked to the `Company`, we pick the `friend` value for the first `Customer` of these customers. This is what the annotation is doing.

Finally we filter out the `Company`s that do not have a `friend` as last `Customer`.

Comment: What happens if I do this `Company.objects.filter(customer__friend=True).order_by('-customer__created_at')?
`

Comment: @daneilJames: you simply obtain all `Company`s that have *at least* one `Customer` that is a friend. The `Company` will be repeated in the `QuerySet` as many times as there are related `Customer`s that are friends, and the `Company`s will be sorted by the `created_at` of these `Customer`s.